# How do I remove blank spaces and blank commas from this?

Tags: php, regex, arrays

```
$str = 1,gmail,6.69%,2,google,3.01%,3,google maps,0.98;
```

I want to trim numbers from the above(not the percentage one) so:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<!\w|\.)\d+/', '', $str);
```

the result is

```
,gmail,6.69%,,google,3.01%,,google maps,0.98;
```

but this gives me blank spaces and commas. How do I get rid of that? Not all commas just the one that is blank.

Comment: You can include the comma in your match so it will be replaced. Just think about beginning/end of line, will have to do something special there. It will probably be an ugly regexp.

Comment: Why should the `0.98` not be replaced? It's a number, and not part of a percentage...

Answer (score 4):

I decided to split it up and process it individually. If anything, it is much easier to read IMO.

```
$values = explode(',', $str);

$values = preg_grep('/^\d+(\.\d+)?\z/', $values, PREG_GREP_INVERT);

$str = join(',', $values);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/a3U3sso9).